# How to remove db entries from Magento to construct a copy of site with reduced Mysql

Tags: database, magento

Want to construct a magento site offline.

Online site has lots of DB entries and for many reasons want to avoid data base entries not required to run catalog( e.g : customer, orders,quote,logs etc).

Is there a single module or code which is run will work.
What approach is recommended.

Comment: Could you be a little more precise on what you are trying to achieve? Do you only need the DB Structure or do you need some data?

Comment: Basically I do have a live site.Its data base is 800 MB. I plan to construct it offline. I don't want customer,order,log etc database values that are populated due to activity on website.I just want data that is required to run website on My local server.

Comment: There's no script or module that could do it for you. Just export the database and truncate the table that you don't want (customer, log, order, shipment, credit card, payment, etc). That would be the easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do.